# How can i export and import my plugin option Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to export the plugin options that I created.

```
if(!get_option('myplugin_opts') ){
  add_option('myplugin_opts');
}
```

and also I want to know how I could import the options to WordPress for my plugin, thanks

Comment: is there any information about what your plugin options are? Or what you mean by import/export? Are you trying to build an import/export page in your plugin? Or are you trying to copy the options from one site to another? Or build a CLI command? Any context you can add would be super helpful

Comment: You could export them using either `get_option($name)` on all your keys, or extracting them from `wp_load_alloptions()` array if they're autoloaded options (default). Make a JSON file or just string and download it, read it later and use `set_option($name, $value)` to import each option individually.

Comment: @TomJNowell yes i'm trying to build export and import page in my plugin, so people who gonna use my plugin will copy the options from one site to another if they do backup

Comment: do you know how to create empty/blank menus and pages in WP Admin? If we can narrow it down to the specific part that isn't clear to you it will help when writing the answer